# Java: вывод разных текстовых сообщений у одноуровневых собственных/custom исключений

Tags: java, исключения

Решаю задачу на [исключения](https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/2480). Задана следующая иерархия собственных исключений:

```
class RootException extends Exception { }

class AException extends RootException { }

class BException extends AException { }

class CException extends AException { }

class DException extends RootException { }
```

Нужно написать код в тело метода, который выводил бы определённое сообщение в зависимости от того, какое исключение было выброшено.

Я сделал так:

```
public static void methodCatchingExceptions() {
    try {
        methodThrowingExceptions();
    } catch (BException e) {
        System.out.println("A OR B");
    } catch (CException e) {
        System.out.println("C");
    } catch (AException e) {
        System.out.println("A OR B");
    } catch (DException e) {
        System.out.println("ROOT OR D");
    } catch (RootException e) {
        System.out.println("ROOT OR D");
    }
}
```

Решение в целом правильное, но код "не чистый". 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Система, видимо, хочет, чтобы я одноуровневые исключения `BException`и `CException`, а также `AException` и `DException` записывал в одних catch'ах, как-то так:

.......
} catch (BException | CException e) {
.......

Но как в таком случае выводить различные сообщения в таких catch'ах?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете проверить переменную на принадлежность к классу:

```
if (e.getClass() == AException.class) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо **[shu512](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/358531/shu512)** за подсказку. В итоге получилось всё сделать с помощью тернарных выражений:

```
public static void methodCatchingExceptions() {

        try {
        methodThrowingExceptions();
        } catch (BException | CException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getClass() == BException.class   ? "A OR B" : "C");
        } catch (AException | DException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getClass() == AException.class  ? "A OR B" : "ROOT OR D");
        } catch (RootException e) {
            System.out.println("ROOT OR D");
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Она ругается на копипасту, которая у тебя неправильная. Для `BException` не может быть `A or B`, ты точно знаешь это `B`. Тоже самое для `AException` - `B` к этому месту уже перехвачены, поэтому это точно `A`. Тоже самое с `ROOT OR D`.

Исправь все `System.out.println` и предупреждений больше не будет.

А если по заданию делать, то

```
public static void methodCatchingExceptions() {
    try {
        methodThrowingExceptions();
    } catch (CException e) {
        System.out.println("C");
    } catch (AException e) {
        System.out.println("A OR B");
    } catch (RootException e) {
        System.out.println("ROOT OR D");
    }
}
```